# Access 2010 VBA or query a table and calculate the results

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a table that contains prices from several agents and from several airlines, they were divided into groups by weight charges.

Depending on the airport of departure (POL/C) and arrival (POD/C), I check all the prices and I have to use the best one. But to show the price alternatives.

Each airline has its own method of calculation, therefore I have to check.

Table contains the following information:

```
ID = AutoNumber, Long Integer
A/CODE = Number, Long Integer
AGENT = Text,
POL/C = Text,
POL = Text,
POD/C = Text,
POD = Text,
IATA = Text,
Airline = Text,
UPDATE = Date/Time, Short Date
EXPIRY DATE = Date/Time, Short Date
CURRENCY = Text,
M/M = Number, Double (Minimum weight accepted)
-45 = Number, Double (price for the weight between 1 and 45)
+45 = Number, Double (price for the weight starting from 45 to 100)
+100 = Number, Double (price for the weight starting from 100 to 300)
+300 = Number, Double (price for the weight starting from 300 to 500)
+500 = Number, Double (price for the weight starting from 500 to 1000)
+1000 = Number, Double (price for the weight starting from 1000)
FSC = Number, Double
SSC = Number, Double
ScGw = Yes/No, Yes/No
FREQUENCY = Text,
TT = Number, Long Integer
T/S = Yes/No, Yes/No
```

From the beginning it will have two weights as follows:

1. actual total weight (GW - gross weight)
2. calculated weight by volume (VW)

   if GW > VW then..
   calculation is based on the higher value (GW)
   else
   calculation is based on the higher value (VW)

**example:**
VW = 405 kgs and GW = 222 kgs then use higher value

FSC and SSC is added to the price if any.
Where is calculated on weight (VW) and If ScGw = Yes THEN the weight is different account and is calculated using (GW)
example:
Air freight = euro 0.25 / kgs (x 405 kgs VW)
Fuel + security = euro 1.1 / kgs (x 222 kgs GW)
If ScGw = No THEN calculate the normal VW
example:
Air freight = euro 0.25 / kgs (x 405 kgs VW)
Fuel + security = euro 1.1 / kgs (x 405 kgs VW)

```
If the calculation is made according to GW, 
then add the FSC and SSC automatically and without having to count, 
if ScGw = Yes / No
```

Values of GW and VW we have already calculated in another form and only need to be use.
airport of departure (POL/C) and arrival (POD/C) is already selected in another form.

If you can help me, as a few days simply fail to find any solution. I am writing full pages without any good result.
Thanks to all who respond.

---

I'm stuck at the moment and with the error:

> Run-time error ‘3061’:
>   Too few parameters. Expected 2

I do not know what the problem is...

```
Public Sub CalculPret()

Dim da As Database
Dim rec As Recordset
Dim PolCboV As String
Dim PodCboV As String
Dim strSQL As String
Dim GrossWeight As Double
Dim VolumeWeight As Double
Dim CalcWeight As Double
Dim CalcWeightScGw As Double
Dim CalcPrice As Double
Dim TotalPrice As Double

PolCboV = [Forms]![DimensionsQry]![PolCbo]
PodCboV = [Forms]![DimensionsQry]![PodCbo]

strSQL = "SELECT Prices_List.ID, Prices_List.[A/CODE], Prices_List.AGENT, Prices_List.[POL/C], Prices_List.POL, Prices_List.[POD/C], Prices_List.POD, Prices_List.IATA, Prices_List.AIRLINE, Prices_List.UPDATE, Prices_List.[EXPIRY DATE], Prices_List.CURRENCY, Prices_List.[M/M], Prices_List.[-45], Prices_List.[+45], Prices_List.[+100], Prices_List.[+300], Prices_List.[+500], Prices_List.[+1000], Prices_List.FSC, Prices_List.SSC, Prices_List.ScGw, Prices_List.FREQUENCY, Prices_List.TT, Prices_List.[T/S]"
strSQL = strSQL & " FROM Prices_List"
strSQL = strSQL & " WHERE (((Prices_List.[POL/C])=PolCboV) AND ((Prices_List.[POD/C])=PodCboV)); "

Set da = CurrentDb
Set rec = da.OpenRecordset(strSQL)

    If rec.RecordCount = 0 Then
        rec.Close
        Exit Sub
    Else
            GrossWeight = [Forms]![DimensionsQry]![Text34]
            VolumeWeight = [Forms]![DimensionsQry]![Text36]

        If GrossWeight > VolumeWeight Then
            CalcWeight = GrossWeight
        Else
            If ScGw = "Yes" Then
                CalcWeight = GrossWeight
            Else
                CalcWeight = VolumeWeight
            End If
        End If
        rec.MoveFirst
            Do Until rec.EOF
                Select Case CalcWeight
                  Case 1 To 44
                    CalcPrice = rec![-45]
                  Case 45 To 99
                    CalcPrice = rec![+45]
                  Case 100 To 299
                    CalcPrice = rec![+100]
                  Case 300 To 499
                    CalcPrice = rec![+300]
                  Case 500 To 999
                    CalcPrice = rec![+500]
                  Case Is >= 1000
                    CalcPrice = rec![+1000]
                End Select

                If CalcWeight = GrossWeight Then
                    CalcPrice = CalcPrice + rec!FSC + rec!SSC
                    TotalPrice = CalcPrice * CalcWeight
                Else
                    TotalPrice = (CalcPrice * CalcWeight) + ((rec!FSC + rec!SSC) * GrossWeight)
                End If
                MsgBox TotalPrice
            rec.MoveNext
            Loop
    End If
rec.Close

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried to rearrange your rules into execution sequence.

I have added the following variables:

- CalcWeight: The weight to be used in the calculation
- CalcPrice: The price to be used in the calculation
- TotalPrice: Price based on weight, standard price, fuel and security

Does the following look about right?

```
If GrossWeight > VolumeWeight Then
  CalcWeight = GrossWeight
Else
  If ScGw = "Yes" Then
    CalcWeight = GrossWeight
  Else
    CalcWeight = VolumeWeight
  End If
End If

Select Case CalcWeight
  Case 1 To 44
    CalcPrice = Price(-45)
  Case 45 to 99
    CalcPrice = Price(+45)
  Case 100 To 299
    CalcPrice = Price(+100)
  Case 300 To 499
    CalcPrice = Price(+300)
  Case 500 To 999
    CalcPrice = Price(500)
  Case Is >= 1000
    CalcPrice = Price(1000)
End Select

' I am unclear about adding FSC and SSC to CalcPrice.
' It appears to be based on which weight is used but
' it may be more complicated. 

If CalcWeight = GrossWeight Then
  CalcPrice = CalcPrice + FSC + SSC
End If

TotalPrice = CalcPrice * CalcWeight
```

**New section in response to extra question**

I have two problems:

- You do not say which statement gives the 3061 error although I suspect I know.
- I have not used Access for some years.

Everything that follows is general advice that may help you isolate the cause of the error.

**Issue 1**

```
strSQL = "SELECT Prices_List.ID, Prices_List.[A/CODE], Prices_List.AGENT, Prices_List.[POL/C], Prices_List.POL, Prices_List.[POD/C], Prices_List.POD, Prices_List.IATA, Prices_List.AIRLINE, Prices_List.UPDATE, Prices_List.[EXPIRY DATE], Prices_List.CURRENCY, Prices_List.[M/M], Prices_List.[-45], Prices_List.[+45], Prices_List.[+100], Prices_List.[+300], Prices_List.[+500], Prices_List.[+1000], Prices_List.FSC, Prices_List.SSC, Prices_List.ScGw, Prices_List.FREQUENCY, Prices_List.TT, Prices_List.[T/S]"
```

I do not like long statements that run off the page.  I would have typed this as:

```
strSQL = "SELECT Prices_List.ID, Prices_List.[A/CODE], Prices_List.AGENT, " & _
         "Prices_List.[POL/C], Prices_List.POL, Prices_List.[POD/C],  " & _
         "Prices_List.POD, Prices_List.IATA, Prices_List.AIRLINE, " & _
         "Prices_List.UPDATE, Prices_List.[EXPIRY DATE], Prices_List.CURRENCY, " & _
         "Prices_List.[M/M], Prices_List.[-45], Prices_List.[+45], " & _
         "Prices_List.[+100], Prices_List.[+300], Prices_List.[+500],  " & _
         "Prices_List.[+1000], Prices_List.FSC, Prices_List.SSC, " & _
         "Prices_List.ScGw, Prices_List.FREQUENCY, Prices_List.TT, " & _
         "Prices_List.[T/S]"
```

**Issue 2**

Do you need all these fields?  When you have picked the best price you will need `AGENT` or `A/CODE`.  If you do not need `ID`, `IATA`, `AIRLINE`, why select them?

**Issue 3**

You have a field CURRENCY which you do not use.  Is this correct?

**Issue 4**

```
Set da = CurrentDb
```

I assume CurrentDb is a global variable because it is not declared or set within this subroutine.

**Issue 5**

```
Set rec = da.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
```

I have googled "Access Error 3061" and have received lots of questions and answers about this error.  Perhaps one will help you.

If I understand correctly, `Prices_List` is not a table but a query with parameters and you have not included the parameters.

**Issue 5**

```
MsgBox TotalPrice
```

While you are trying to get your program working, `Debug.Print` is more useful than `MsgBox`.

Click on one of the early statements in this routine to place the cursor in it.  Click F9.  The statement will go brown to indicate it is a breakpoint.

Run your program in the normal way.  When it gets to the brown statement, it will stop and display the module.  The brown statement will be both brown and yellow.  Brown because it is a breakpoint; yellow because it is the statement about to be executed.  Click F8; one statement will be executed and the next statement will become the yellow one.

You can step through your program statement by statement checking what is happening.  If you hover over a variable, its current value will be displayed.  If a statement gives an error, you can change it and try again.

You can have as many breakpoints as you like.  Clicking F5 causes the program to run until the next breakpoint.  With F5 and F8 you can control which bits of your program you examine.

`Debug.Assert rec!AGENT <> "Acme Inc"` can be very useful if one part of your program is failing.  This debug assert will stop the program if the agent is "Acme Inc".  The syntax is `Debug.Assert boolean expression`.  With the correct boolean expression you can stop your program where ever you want.

At the bottom of the editor screen you should see the Immediate window.  If you do not, click `Ctrl+G`.

```
Debug.Print rec!AGENT & " " & TotalPrice
```

will output `Acme Inc 543.21` to the Immediate Window and carry on.  With MsgBox the program stops and you have to write down the value.  The Immediate Window has a limit of two or three hundred lines which you can scroll up and down or copy to NotePad.

**Summary**

I hope the above helps.  Best of luck.

Comment: 0 down vote accept
 

Thank you very much Tony!
I'm stuck at the moment and with the error:
Run-time error ‘3061’:
Too few parameters. Expected 2
I do not know what the problem is...

Comment: @ Catalin Anton.  I have added an extra section to my answer which I hope will help.

Comment: Thank you very much Tony! I will try to use the advice that I received from you. For now I added a lot, so I can use the information. **Anyway you have given me the start!**

Answer (score 0):

the line

strSQL = strSQL & " WHERE (((Prices_List.[POL/C])=PolCboV) AND ((Prices_List.[POD/C])=PodCboV));"

should read

strSQL = strSQL & " WHERE (((Prices_List.[POL/C])='" & PolCboV & "') AND ((Prices_List.[POD/C])='" & PodCboV & "'));"

because PolCbov & PodCbov are variables in your code, you want their values in the SQL not their names

Comment: Thank you! Chris Padgham -now going ok, now just need to do to give me and results in a table to be able to choose which is the best solution. From 10 years since I have not done programming, and many things that I no longer remember. Thanks to those who use personal time to teach others!